# Why getDerivedStateFromProps() is designed as static

Tags: reactjs, api, architecture

From API and React architecture design perspective, Is there any concern that make it static?

Answer (score 1):

> Making certain lifecycles static to prevent unsafe access of instance properties.
>   https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0006-static-lifecycle-methods.md#goal

As stated from the above proposal, the new APIs (including deprecating the old ones) are designed to make async-compatible react components happen.

<sub>Disclaimer: If you choose to try bleeding edge thing, you're already bleeding ¯_(ツ)_/¯</sub>